# Open sharepoint workflow in web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have created a site and have added a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010.

But I don't know how to open that workflow in web, but I'm able to open the site in web.

How to do it ? Because SharePoint Designer is in server and I need to work on these workflows in my machine.

Comment: as far as I have came accross, there is only standalone version of SharePoint designer, and no webversion.

Comment: SP Designer can be installed on any client machine. You should just make sure, that you start the SP Designer with a user that has the rights to use and edit the site with the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a workflow is created in SharePoint designer there is no way to edit it from web, the only way is to install SharePoint designer on your machine and you should be able to open and edit the workflows,

you can download SPD from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491)